# Can't Add Service Reference to New Console App

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, service-reference

I am trying to add a Service Reference to my brand new console app and I am getting the following error:

> Unable to check out the current file. The file may be read-only or locked, or you may need to check out the file manually.

Ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ec2ktk.aspx

I am not even connected to source control; this is a new project and I didn't check the "Include in source control" checkbox.

I have also tried making the entire project NOT read-only by right-clicking it and unchecking the Read Only box under Properties.  However, the project's folder is still read-only...  It won't change for some reason.

How can I add my service reference to my project?

Comment: This issue is solved by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21428665/116818

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is; I was trying to add a Service Reference, but I should have actually tried adding a **Web Reference**.  As per this page:

> Its because you picked service reference, which generates a WCF based stub, which uses different classes and a different programming model. You need to make sure you're creating a web reference, not a service reference (unless you want to use the WCF based stuff), In VS.NET 2008, **the web reference option IIRC, is hidden under the advanced button on the add service reference dialog.**

Ref.  http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/general_development/message-id/33779/print-single-message/false/page/1

Comment: I think you may not be totally correct, as I faced this issue on my PC  and when I turned to another pc trying to create the same new project adding new service reference worked smoothly so it is not what the article trying to say. please comment !

Comment: @AhmedNazmy Not much to say, all I know is, this solution worked for me at the time.  Also, this is VS 2008; so it depends on which version you are using.

Answer (score 6):

Try to Run Visual Studio As Administrator.
It seems like a problem in access to some directory.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is a bug in Git source code provider. See here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789876/unable-to-add-web-service-when-using-git-source-code-provider

To workaround, turn it off when adding a service reference. Or check other workarounds in the above article. Still not fixed in VS 2013 Update4

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered, but before trying everything else in the answers, restart visual studio. This just happened to me and 4 other people in my team. Seems to be a problem with visual studio 2013 and not 2012.

Answer (score 1):

To me the solution was:
1)Removing the Service Reference then adding it again
2)In your web.config, you should check if adding the new reference adds another endpoint, if it does, you should remove one.