# Problems adding a service reference to a WP8 app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I try to add a service reference to the `http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL` web service. I go to Add service reference, it discovers it just fine, but when i try to hit OK, I get the error:

> Unable to check out current file. The file may be read-only or locked, or you may need to check the file out manually.

I also tried adding a web reference under the "Advanced" tab, but there isnt any option to do so.

I tried doing so in a 7.1 targeted app, same error.
My friend is doing this on a Visual Studio 2010, and he gets no such error.

Comment: This sounds like VS was attempting to update one of your project files but hit a local filesystem error.  If you're using a version control system, are you sure all your project files are checked out and writable?  FWIW, I was able to add this service reference to my WP8 project in VS2013 without hitting this error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I found a solution: run Visual Studio as Administrator.

Answer (score 44):

Follow these step, hope it will work:

1. Go to `Debug` → `Options`.
2. Select `Source Control` in the list.
3. Under `Current Source ControlPlug-in` drop down select `none`.

Comment: This solution also worked for me in VS2013, with a newly-created test project.

Comment: not sure if that is a typo but should it be Tools -> Options instead of Debug -> Options? is for VS2013

Comment: @ChocoSmith Might depend on how your UI is setup.  I found it under Debug > Options and Settings > Source Control in VS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with Updating Service reference.

My solution was :

- Right click on the Service reference
- Check Out for edit
- Then try to update the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the suggested tricks worked, but when I  opened the Advanced dialog and selected Add Web Reference all went well.